# Helm chart template: Require that values (in values.yaml) for nodeSelector exists as labels on nodes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, go-templates

I was trying to make sure that users configuring nodeSelector values in a chart will fill in labels that actually match the ones on the nodes in the kubernetes cluster and was wondering if anyone knows a way to do this?

My initial idea was to use something in style with

```yaml
{{ required "nodeSelector needs to be set to a label of one of the nodes" (has .Values.nodeSelector (lookup "v1" "nodes" "--show-labels" "")) }}
```

This would, in theory, require that the nodeSelector values exist in the map of labels.

Would "looping" over the values and using `eq` be better? Or any other smart ideas?

The first obvious problem here was that nodeSelector values are defined `key: value` for example:

```yaml
nodeSelector:
  product: monitoring
```

While Node labels are written as `key=value`.

The second obvious problem is that I get an error telling me I cant use the *has* function on type *map*. Is there a way to convert a map to a list in a neat way or another solution to this?

Really appreciate any feedback, so just write! :)